# How to "link" different objects that have wind physics

Tags: physics, vertex-groups

I'm trying to make a stand for a poster i designed, the concept is that the poster is held in place by two paper pins which themselves are attached via a string to a metal bar above, now i got how to make the poster flop with the wind with vertex groups, but how do i connect all of them so that they are attached one to another, and and make them react together to the wind?

[image: View of the scene]

[image: You can see here that only the poster is moving]

Answer (score 0):

a very "easy" solution is to model it as one object like this:

[image]

use the two selected vertices as pin group and give it a cloth modifier.

add some wind with noise, maybe increase the stiffness values like this:

[image]

and you get:

[image]

less wind, but some different preset cloth values:

[image]

[image]